# Annotate gem: no such file to load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

When I run the commands for the [Annotate Model Gem](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) to annotate my models I get the following errors and I used these two ways to install the gem:

```
$ annotate --exclude tests, fixtures
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/annotate-2.5.0/bin/annotate:3:i
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/bin/annotate:19:in `<main>'

$ bundle exec annotate --exclude tests, fixtures
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/annotate-2.5.0/bin/annotate:3:in `require': no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition (LoadError)
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/annotate-2.5.0/bin/annotate:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/annotate:19:in `load'
        from c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/annotate:19:in `<main>'
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem "rails", "3.1.0"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"

group :development do
  gem "annotate", "2.5.0"
end
```

**command line:**

```
$ gem install annotate
Successfully installed annotate-2.5.0
1 gem installed
```

How can I get this gem to work?

Comment: Is the group blob in a Gemfile? If so you probably just need to bundle install before you bundle exec.

Comment: @MattGlover Yeah it is. Let me edit my question.

Comment: What version of rake are you using? `bundle exec rake --version`

Comment: @iltempo included too. It's `"rake", "0.8.7"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update rake please. `Rake::DSL` has been introduced in version **0.9**.

```
bundle update rake
```

Comment: Ok Cool. I uninstalled `rake 0.8.7` and went to `"rake", "0.9.2.2"`. Thanks.